# Log-likelihood function of the noncentral t-distribution

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

I'm trying to find an analytical expression of the log-likelihood function of the noncentral t-distribution as described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_t-distribution.

It is implemented somehow i Python's SciPy stats module (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.nct.html) but I can't seem to find any expression for the log-likelihood function in the source code.

Is there an analytical expression of the log-likelihood function for the noncentral t-distribution, and if so, can someone help me find it?

Thanks,

Kristofer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log-likelihood function is a function of the parameters that is based on the [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_t-distribution#Probability_density_function) $f(x;\nu,\mu)$ where $x$ is replaced with data and one or more of the parameters ($\nu$ and $\mu$) are taken as independent variables.

So, the log-likelihood function for $N$ observations $\{x_i \}_{i=1}^N$ of a noncentrally Student-$t$ distributed random variable is

$$L(\mu, \nu) = \sum_{i=1}^N \log f(x_i; \nu, \mu)$$

In SciPy, there is a noncentrally Student-$t$ distributed random variable called `scipy.stats.nct`; you can access its probability density function using the `pdf` method.

One way to create the log-likelihood function (for one observation) would be to do something along the lines of

```
L = lambda mu, nu : nct.logpdf(x, mu, nu)
```

where `x` is an observation defined before.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Riccardo, although I am looking for a more explicit expression, like the second equation in the following section for the Gamma distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Maximum_likelihood_estimation.

Comment: The explicit expression is the log of the function at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_t-distribution#Probability_density_function; if you're asking for a _nice_ expression, sadly there is none :(

Comment: Ah, what a shame, but thanks for the help!